# Adding extra new parameter to header as response in symfony2

Tags: symfony, header, response

I want to send response to the client which should include some details in header which is common, let say `userID` and others datails in the body. How to add such new parameters to header of response,

I tried,

```php
public function postAPIAction()
{
    $jsonData = $this->getRequest()->getContent();
    $decodePostRequest = json_decode($jsonData, true);

    // processing is involved........

    $uniqueKey=$this->generateUniqueKey();
    $response = new Response();
    $response->headers->add(array('userId' => $uniqueKey));

    return new Response(json_encode(array('errorcode' => '1'), true));
}
```

which is not working.

Comment: This should work. Please, paste more code from your controller

Comment: Did you `return` the created request from your action?

Comment: okay..thanks...i got mistake..i was returning new response.Thanks

Comment: Leaving answers in the comments is not good, so I've provided the answer you could check as the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return the response you've set the headers on instead of creating a new one in the `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating a new response in your return.
You should use the response you created before.

```
$response = new Response();
$response->headers->add(array('userId' => $uniqueKey));
$response->setContent(...);

return $response;
```